# How do I request data (in form of image) to server in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How do I request data (in form of image) to server in Flask?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect,url_for, Response
from flask import Markup, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_IMAGE = '/home/tarak/Pictures/Wallpapers/m31.jpg'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg','png','txt','jpeg','gif'])
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/image', methods=['POST'])
def image():        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['UPLOAD_IMAGE']   
        request_    
        print("Image Received!!")
        return "This is the homepage."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am getting 404 Not Found Error on `localhost:5000/image`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because, your route `@app.route("/image", methods=['POST'])` accepts only a `post` request, and when opening the URL in your browser it recieves a `'GET'` request.

If you modify it to `@app.route("/image", methods=['GET', 'POST'])` or remove `methods=..` you will see in your browser "This is the homepage"

Comment: And adjust usage of `if request.method == "POST"` to handle a GET